# Laravel: immutable Trait

Tags: laravel, immutability, traits

I need that when a document is considered closed, you won't be able to modify, update or delete it anymore.

I was thinking to use a trait like an "ImmutableTrait".
I've done this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait ImmutableTrait
{
 protected $isImmutable = false;

 public function setAttribute($key, $value)
 {
     if ($this->isImmutable) {
        return $this;
 }

  return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
 }
}
```

Then in my model:

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\ImmutableTrait;

class MedicalRecord extends Model
{
 use ImmutableTrait;


 public function closeDocument()
 {
    $this->isImmutable = true;
 }
}
```

---

Finally the controller:

---

```
public function closeDocument(Document $document)
{
    .....
    $document->closeDocument();
    $document->saveorfail();
}
```

---

Then, if I try to retrieve the closed model and update a field, I shouldn't be able to do it:

---

```
Route::put('{document}/updateStatus', 'DocumentController@updateStatus');


class DocumentController extends Controller
{
  ....
  public function updateStatus(Document $document)
  {
    $document->status= "TEST";
    $document->saveorfail();
  }
}
```

---

Calling the API with the id of a closed document, should fail the update, but this is not happening. The field is updated normally.

Obviously I'm missing something. But what?

Thank you all!

Comment: field is updated how? what code are you using to do this 'update'?  also you are checking for a member variable named `immutableCheck` but you are setting a member variable named `isImmutable`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I will edit it.
I'm updating a field just calling: 
$document->status= "Example";
$document->saveorfail();

Comment: and this is the same instance of the model you called the `closeDocument` method on?

Comment: Yes I retrieve the closed document and I call the update method on it. It's like the "isImmutable" variable is not persisted.

Comment: We need to see more code on the document object and how you use it. Not an fictional example but where your code fails, i would guess you are maybe instantiating a new model or similar.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what's the problem. Obviously the "isImmutable" variable is not persisted, right? So if I try to retrieve the closed model from the Database, a new model is instantiated with "isImmutable" set to false by default, am I right? Btw I'll add some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference if anyone needs this.
I ended up creating the following trait:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Traits;
use App\Exceptions\ImmutableModelException;

trait ImmutableModelTrait {
 
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        if ($this->isClosed)
        {
            throw new ImmutableModelException();
        }
        else {
            //do what Laravel normally does
            $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }  
}
```

The problem with my first solution, as @mrhn stated in one comment, was that I was searching for the "isImmutable" variable on a new model instance but I wasn't persisting that variable in the DB table.

So now my "Document" table has a field "isClosed" that becomes true when the document is considered closed.